# Trying to send multiple parameters to ASP.NET webAPI post method results server error 500

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Iam trying to send multiple parameters with complex datatype to POST method in WebAPI but it fails with 500 server error. I will be greatful if somebody help me finding what is missing ?

**Ajax:**

```
var x={}
var y={}
    $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type: "POST",
             data: JSON.stringify({xDto:x,yDto:y}),
             url: "/api/Info/PostInfo",
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
             success: function(data) {
             }
             error: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
})
```

**Action:**

```
 public IHttpActionResult PostInfo(InfoDto xDto,InfoDto yDto)
        {
             //post xDto and yDto to db
         }
```

Comment: You don't pass two objects and you can't. You just pass an object with two  propeties `xDto` and `yDto`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the API Parameter to an `InfoDto` array and retrieve it from the body:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostInfo([FromBody]InfoDto[] xDtos)
{

}
```

You also have to change your JavaScript to something like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify([x, y])
```